# copy image picked by user into larger image

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap

i have an app that lets the user pick an image from the device. I create a Bitmap from it and at a certain point i want to copy that image into a larger image. Not scaling it just copy it at a certain position. I tried the following:

```
ActivityResultLauncher<Intent> startActivityIntent = registerForActivityResult(
    new ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
    result -> {
        try {
            img = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(ImageDecoder.createSource(getContentResolver(), result.getData().getData()));
            width = img.getWidth();
            height = img.getHeight();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
});
```

and then later

```
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width+100,height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
canvas.drawBitmap(img,100,0,null);
```

but i get the error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Software rendering doesn't support hardware bitmaps`

I get a similar error when i try to access the pixels of img. How can i achieve that?